# Pandas calculation - index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, dataframe

I am loading 2 comma seperated values and one identifier from a csv into a dataframe. After that, I replace the commas with dots and cast them to a float:

```
tzeitverbrauch = []

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))
df.Aufwand_geplant = df.Aufwand_geplant.astype(float).fillna(0.0)
df.Aufwand_laufend_ist = df.Aufwand_laufend_ist.astype(float).fillna(0.0)
```

After that I am calling a function which calculates the difference for these 2 values for one identifier:

```
def calculate(identifier):

    aufwand_geplant = df.loc[(df.Identifier == identifier), 'Aufwand_geplant'].values[0]
    aufwand_ist = df.loc[(df.Identifier == identifier), 'Aufwand_laufend_ist'].values[0]

    x = aufwand_ist - aufwand_geplant

    tzeitverbrauch.append(x)


for x in df_identifier:
    calculate(x)
```

However, for some strange reason I have results and everything is okay when i debug the code but on some point the exception is popping up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:/PycharmProjects/PycharmProjects/PP-KPI/Levenshtein.py", line 53, 
in   <module> calculate(x)
File "H:/PycharmProjects/PycharmProjects/PP-KPI/Levenshtein.py", line 43, 
in   calculate aufwand_geplant = df.loc[(df.identifier == identifier), 'Aufwand_geplant'].values[0]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

The values here:

```
print(len(df.Aufwand_geplant)) = 125
print(len(df.Aufwand_laufend_ist)) = 125
print(len(df_identifier)) = 125
```

I appreciate some input and help how to identify the problem!

[image]

Comment: What do you see for `(df['identifier'] == identifier).sum()` (print it before your error) ?

Comment: Okay, got a lot of 1 1 1 1 1 1 .. 1 0 (and after the 0, the error appears)

Comment: Thank you @jpp. Your comment helped me to fix my problem. I missed one column in my read_csv!